# How to make one number replace one letter of android:hint, while the hint still remains until I've replaced it all? (android studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm very new to android studio and trying to make a PIN login screen with 4 numbers. I want the number to replace each line of "hint" whenever I type a number. As of now, whenever I type 1 number it removes the whole hint and places the number in the center.

Like this: _ _ _ _
Where "_ _ _ _" is the hint and if I type a number I want one line to be replaced like this: "3 _ _ _"

This is what I have so far:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:ems="5"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:hint="_ _ _ _"
    android:textColorHint="#007272"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="20dp"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:background="#00000000"/>
```

Comment: The requirement you want it can't be fulfill using hint property.It just the hint to get the user know what to write here.

Comment: You can achieve your requirement using so many ways.You can take 4 edit text with background like "_" this.When you type 1st pin and press next it automatically goes to second edit text with this way you can do.

Comment: try out  this [http://lomza.totem-soft.com/pin-input-view-in-android/](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/pin-input-view-in-android/)

Comment: And also check this [https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText](https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText)

Comment: Thank you for answers. I'll check those links as well and get back to you if I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The hint is the text which is shown when there is no text inside the edittext. If you type something for example 3, there is a text inside now so the hint will not be visible. My idea is to add 4 EditText views with the hint "_". You just have to handle the focus then...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.You can change the background with your requirement after change the background like hint you don't need the hint you can remove it.I just post a simple demo the way how you can achieve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="_"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:padding="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="_"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:padding="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="_"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:padding="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="_"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:padding="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'll try this, I'm new to this so might take a while. Thank you for answers!